# forcing hide and show region to stay open. Switching from > to v

Tags: oracle-apex, show-hide

I have a region test3 static ID mytest. Then I have a sub region Test3 sub, static id test3subregion. The
Sub region has a template of Hide and Show Region.  Under Test3 sub I have 2 text boxes.
P200_FNAME, and P200_LNAME.

If P200_FNAME has data I want to force the hide and show region (Test3 sub) to stay open.

I thought I could use the following to force the parent Test3 sub to stay open if I do it onload
$('#P200_FNAME').show().parent().show();

It does not work.

I thought I could use this but this hides and shows the region as a block.  It will not force the selector from
this > to v to force the region open.   What could I use to accomplished this.

$x_Show('test3subregion');

I appreciate the help.

Howard

Answer (score 0):

I'm testing on 20.1, on this version this is a "Collapsible" region. Check the browser dev tools to see what happens if you collapse and expand. On my version I see that a class `is-expanded` is added when the region is expanded and `is-collapsed` when it is collapsed. You can add/remove this class with jquery:

```
$( "#mytest" ).removeClass( "is-collapsed" );
$( "#mytest" ).addClass( "is-expanded" );
```

However, the user still has control over the region with the button at that point. I would only use the "show/hide" region if the user has complete control over it himself. For a region for which the visibility is determined by the application I would use a standard region. You can declaratively control show/hide with a dynamic action for those.